# Rails how to map name and id from array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I am getting parent nodes via and outputting them as a sort of bread crumb list, how do I map both the name of the classification and id to bu8ild a link_to?

```
<% @parents.map(&:name).each do |parent| %>
    <%= link_to parent, new_sr_path(class_id: parent, sub: :true), class: "form-control" %><svg ...</svg>
<% end %>

@parents = @classification.ancestors.to_a.reverse if params[:class_id].present?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate through your objects, instead of the names of your objects (generated by the `.map(&:name)` call):

```html
<% @parents.each do |parent| %>
  <%= link_to parent.name, new_sr_path(class_id: parent.id, sub: :true), class: "form-control" %>
<% end %>
```

**NOTE** Having a real instance give you the ability to call all instance methods defined on that object: `parent.name`, `parent.id`, ...

Comment: I swear I tried that ha. Thanks! That is much easier.